# File getting corrupted if user cancels file UPLOAD on WEBDAV repository

Tags: swift, swift5, webdav, nsurlsessionuploadtask

In one of my iOS app, I'm trying to upload a file on `WEBDAV` repository and this is how I'm preparing things for UPLOAD -

```
func createUploadRequest(url: String) -> URLRequest? {
    if let url = URL(string: url) {
        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.setValue("1", forHTTPHeaderField: "Depth")
        request.setValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        return request
    }
    return nil
}

@IBAction func upload() {
    if let request = createUploadRequest(url: url) {
        let sessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "sessionIdentifier")
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        uploadTask = self.session?.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, fromFile: self.fileUrl!)
        self.uploadTask?.resume()
    }

}
```

When upload is in progress and I cancel the `uploadtask` as follows

```
@IBAction func cancelUpload() {
    self.uploadTask?.cancel()
}
```

The upload process gets canceled but the problem here is ***the file is getting corrupted on WEBDAV Server***, which is being uploaded and `uploadtask` is canceled in between.

Strangely this is working fine in iOS 9 and upload process getting canceled properly without file being corrupted but iOS version 12 and above file getting corrupted.
I didn't check the behaviour on iOS 10 or 11 though.

Please help me get this issue resolved. Thank you in advance.

**Please note that this bug persists with/without lock on WEBDAV resource**